# When merging branches, does git ever use the commits in between the merge-base and the merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

For example, suppose we have the two branches "master" and "alt".  The "master" branch has commits "A," "B," "C," and "D" while the "alt" branch has commits "A," "B'," and "D".  Commit "D" represents the merge from alt into master.  Here is my attempt at drawing this relationship:

`A <-- B <-- C <--- D
 \                /
  \---B'<--------/`

Question: Since commit `A` is clearly the merge-base of `B'` and `C`, **does git at all need the information found in `B` (i.e., the commit in between the merge commit and the merge-base)?** If the answer is no, are there any special cases where the answer is yes?

Comment: Here's maybe another way to put it: if you used rebase to squash B and C together, would it make a difference to the merge?

Answer (score 2):

The concept of "... at all need the information found in `B` ..." isn't particularly clear. But perhaps understanding what goes on under the hood in `git merge` would help you answer your own question...

Given your described tree, and your described method of getting there (`git checkout master; git merge alt` - although you should know that this does not cause `alt` to also point at `D`, so your assertion that `alt` contains the `D` commit is incorrect, unless you did something else to affect that), what happens is that `git merge` finds `A` as the merge base. It then creates deltas between `A` and `C` (the tip of the pre-merge `master`) and between `A` and `B'` (tip of `alt`), and then attempts to combine those two deltas cleanly and apply the combined delta to `A` - this new state becomes `D`. If the two branch deltas cannot be combined cleanly, then you have a conflict - the most likely cause for that is that `B'` changed some lines that were also changed in either `B` or `C`, but not in the same way.

So, strictly speaking, no, `git` does not look specifically at commit `B` during the merge process; however, since the changes introduced by `B` are present also in `C` (to the extent that `C` didn't undo them, anyway), then the "information found in `B`" is "used" in a sense...

Answer (score 0):

Git does need the information of `B` and `C`, as you phrase it, as these commits might modify the same lines of code as commit `B'` does, which would result in a conflict that you need to resolve in merge commit `D`.

Comment: Sorry, I mispoke in my question. I don't mean `B` and `C`, I just mean `B`. Isn't all of the information that git needs found in `C` and `A`? How could git need `B`?

Comment: Put differently: if `B` modifies the same lines of code that `B'` does, then those lines of code will either (i) be overriden in `C` or (ii) be reflected in `C` *anyway*.  So don't we NOT need the information found in `B` to make this merge?

Comment: I think you're confused about the fact which information is contained in a commit. Each commit only stores the delta to its parent. That is, just the single commit `C` itself does not contain the information from `B`. You can easily verify this by running `git show C` which does not show any changes from `B`. What probably confuses you is that when you say `git checkout C` you still get a working tree that includes the changes from `B`. But that's because `checkout` refers to the state of tree after applying `C`, not to just `C` itself (which would not make sense anyway).